# When is safeAreaInsetsDidChange called?

Tags: ios, swift, safearealayoutguide

I am aware that `safeAreaInsetsDidChange`is being called when the view is first laying out its subviews. What I'm wondering is under what circumstances/events this could be called again while the screen is still presented (iPad slide-over for example)

Comment: I'm guessing there are following cases: orientation change, incoming call, started call, ended call, split screen. In future I'm sure folding a phone will trigger this too.

Comment: I tried orientation change and slide-over, but not the other ones you mentioned. Thank you, I'll definitely investigate that!

Answer (score 0):

It is called when the safeArea of the view did change. To understnad that you need to know what is safeArea.It is the area that is not covered by bars(navigation, tool, and tab).

These too links might help you.

- [safeAreaInsets](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891103-safeareainsets)
- [iOS Safe Area](https://medium.com/rosberryapps/ios-safe-area-ca10e919526f)

Comment: I'm quite aware what `safeArea` is, my question was about which cases would trigger a call to `safeAreaInsetsDidChange`